# i cant approach to authorize view from one controller view to another

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to move from Home controller view Index to another view authorize view which keyword can  I use? RedirectToAction isn't working for me.
RedirectToAction is getting me back to login.

Comment: Please can you show some code. That will make it easier to help you.

Comment: HomeController{

public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Contact(USER u)
        {

            USER U = d.USERs.Where(x => x.Email_Id == u.Email_Id && x.Pass == u.Pass).SingleOrDefault();
            
            if (U != null)
            {

               return RedirectToAction("Index","U_data");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Invalid Id or password";
            }
}

this is my one view

Comment: [Authorize]
    public class U_dataController : Controller
    {
        private cs db = new cs();

        USER u =new USER();
        // GET: U_data
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            
            return View(db.U_Datas.ToList().Where(x=>x.D_ID==GPA.IDBHAE));
        }}
this is my second controller i want to move from one controller to this authorize controller but RedirectToAction keyword is not working for me it get me back to login

Comment: Please edit your original question and add the code there. The comments section is not the best place to paste code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a controller and then create a view which will be displayed after your controller will move you to that view. You also need to add a button to use a controller to the layout of your homepage.

Comment: i don't understand what you want to say.

Comment: I am just trying to move from one controller view to another controller Authorized view but RedirectToAction is not working for me.